# Rails routing shorthand when URL path is the same as method name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

One of the entries in my `config/routes.rb`:

```
get "enumerators/job_type", to: "enumerators#job_type"
```

As you can observe, the URL path and the method name that it corresponds to in the controller is the same. Does Rails provide a shorthand in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Rails magic will let you just write: `get "enumerators/job_type"` in your routes file, as long as your controller name is `EnumeratorsController` and the method is `job_type`

Remember you can always check the routes it's creating by running `bundle exec rake routes`

Answer (score 1):

You can use namespace like the below:

```
namespace :enumerators do 
  get "job_type" 
end
```

More info for namespace:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Answer (score 1):

Blending the two answers, here are the best way to the worst way to do the routing:

1. Best

   ```
   namespace :enumerators do 
     get "job_type"
     get "something_else"
   end
   ```
2. Worse

   ```
   get "enumerators/job_type"
   get "enumerators/something_else"
   ```
3. Worst

   ```
   get "enumerators/job_type", to: "enumerators#job_type"
   get "enumerators/something_else", to: "enumerators#something_else"
   ```